# DB cloning on daily basis

Tags: oracle, rman

I have a requirement from one of my teams which is database copy (cloning) from production to my test server on daily basis at a particular time.

I know this is a very simple process which every DBA would perform.

Should I use RMAN duplicate for cloning? Should I use Goldengate? Is there any way I can schedule the same without manual intervention?

Server - RHEL
Database - Oracle 12c/11g

Comment: Would there be much activity update/delete/insert-wise on the test system? You could use flashback to scn & apply archive, if so.

Comment: But on daily basis? what is the best option to go with? Yes activity will be there but not much. Goldengate, as a choice? any inputs?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in a few minutes with storage snapshots/cloning. If you can't do that, just go for RMAN duplicate. Both method can be scripted and scheduled to run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using data pump over a db link.  Set up correctly, you could drop the commands into a shell script and run it from cron.

Watch archive log generation on the target side, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a Physical Standby database and flashback. If your primary does not make to many changes this could be a very valid solution like described in [12.6 Using a Physical Standby Database for Read/Write Testing and Reporting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14239/scenarios.htm#CIHIABDH)
This is fairly easy to script to make it a painless daily exercise.